Drawing nested tubes with TikZ
I am drawing nested tubes in LaTeX with TikZ, currently just drawing nodes and ellipses and using ext.paths.ortho to make the connections. But as the diagram get more complicated it's harder to distinguish the different levels. How would I go about adding a fill to each tube, or perhaps a gradient to give a 3d-like appearance.

This is what I'm hoping to achieve, quick job in MS paint

Here is what I have to draw the diagram.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{tube/.style={draw, ellipse, minimum width=25,minimum height=10}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\dx{1}
\def\dy{2}

\node (p3) at (-2.5*\dx,-0.5*\dy) {$p_3=$};

%Top objects
\node (l1t1) at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
\node (l2t1) [tube] at (0,0) {};
\node [fit=(l2t1)] (l3t1) [thick,tube] {};
%Bottom objects
\node (l1b1) at (-\dx,-\dy) {$\bullet$};
\node (l2b1) [tube] at (-\dx,-\dy) {};
\node [fit=(l2b1)] (l3b1) [thick,tube] {};
\node (l1b2) at (\dx,-\dy) {$\bullet$};
\node (l2b2) [tube] at (\dx,-\dy) {};
\node [fit=(l2b2)] (l3b2) [thick,tube] {};
%Lines
\draw[thick,rounded corners=10] (l3t1.west) |-|[ratio=0.33] (l3b1.west);
\draw[thick,rounded corners=10] (l3t1.east) |-|[ratio=0.33] (l3b2.east);
\draw[rounded corners=5] (l2t1.west) |-|[ratio=0.45] (l2b1.west);
\draw[rounded corners=5] (l2t1.east) |-|[ratio=0.45] (l2b2.east);
\draw[rounded corners] (l2b1.east) r-ud (l2b2.west);
\draw[thick,rounded corners] (l3b1.east) r-ud[ud distance=10] (l3b2.west);
\draw[thick] (l1t1.center) |-|[ratio=0.6] (l1b1.center);
\draw[thick] (l1t1.center) |-|[ratio=0.6] (l1b2.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


See opacity and use it with fill.  Dashed lines and solid lines must be drawn separately.  See arc[start=0,end=180].

Welcome! If you need more than the hint, please provide the code for your current output in the form of a complete but minimal document we can compile.

If you want to fill, you need to create closed paths. So the ellipses are fine on their own, but you really need to construct them as part of complete outlines of the tubes (if you want filling). You can use the ellipse for placement, as cis's answer does, but you still need to trace the path at some point.

Apart from the fact that the ellipses are not hit correctly by the line; and apart from the fact that filling doesn't work without a closed path: I don't see how it gets much easier this way. Switching from 'rounded corners' to 'sharp corners' has a strange syntax and didn't always work and is a similar mess as with the arcs; so I used the arcs for the closed path and the 'rounded corners'.

If you want to draw your ellipses as \node (not as \draw), for whatever reason, you have to add outer sep=0pt so that the lines fit cleanly. Otherwise, you can rescue your MWE if you make it a closed path for the filling. But I think your method is quite complicated (and difficult to understand with the cryptic names, I think something like 'EllipseRight, EllipseAbove' is a bit clearer).

PS: But you will probably also have the problem with the 'rounded corners' and the 'sharp corners'; also with your 'ext.paths.ortho' implementation. I would have liked to have said: rounded corners=3mm, but then...

Thanks for all your comments. The cryptic names work for me, these diagrams can get quite a bit more complicated than what I've posted here, and they are just shorthand for "level x, top \ bottom y". Any other choices I've made a due to pure ignorance, I know very little Tikz and a lot of it comes from copying and pasting bits and pieces from other answers on here. I'm working my way through understanding your solution.

From my point of view, this is mainly mechanical work, without any special features.
It is advisable to always work with relative paths if possible, so that the entire graph is flexible to the input dimensions.
You should also provide your own approach that the helper can work with and try out.
PS: I didn't use opacity (that sometimes causes problems with conversions or something); and arcs only to create 'rounded corners' (that means no elliptical arcs). 
And, oh yes: the entire graph is a 2D-drawing.
Now then, for the fun of drawing with TikZ...
Something like this:

%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[FillStyle/.style={fill=lightgray},]
%% CoSy
\draw[orange, thin, ->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{x}; 
\draw[orange,  thin, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above]{y}; 

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=mytube]
% Default dimensions
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\R{10mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\H{25mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\d{13.5mm}% 2*\d = Middlepointdistance Ellipse left-right
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{17mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\hI{0.4*\h}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\hII{0.7*\h}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\rc{3.5mm}% rounded corners radius

\tikzset{ tube/.pic = {
\coordinate[] (L) at (-\d,0);
\coordinate[] (R) at (\d,0);
\coordinate[] (A) at (0,\H);
%
\path[local bounding box=EllipseAbove] (A) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];
\path[local bounding box=EllipseLeft] (L) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];
\path[local bounding box=EllipseRight] (R) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];
%
\draw[FillStyle] (EllipseRight.west) -- (EllipseRight.east)   
  -- (\d+\R,\h-\rc) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=\rc]
  -- (\R+\rc,\h) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=-\rc]
--  (EllipseAbove.east) -- (EllipseAbove.west)  
  -- (-\R,\h+\rc) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-90, radius=\rc]
  -- (-\d-\R+\rc,\h) arc[start angle=-90, end angle=0, radius=-\rc]
-- (EllipseLeft.west) -- (EllipseLeft.east)  
  -- (-\d+\R, \hI-\rc) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-90, radius=-\rc]
  -- (\d-\R-\rc, \hI) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=\rc]
-- cycle;
%
\draw[FillStyle] (A) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];
\draw[FillStyle] (L) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];
\draw[FillStyle] (R) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];
},}

% 1
\pic{tube};


% 2 (here other dimensions for the inner tube, else 'Default dimensions')
\begingroup
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=gray}}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\R{5mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{15mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\hI{0.6*\h}
\pic{tube};
\endgroup


% 3
\draw[fill=none] (A) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];
\draw[fill=none] (L) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];
\draw[fill=none] (R) ellipse[x radius=\R, y radius=0.5*\R];


% 4
\draw[thick] (L) -- (-\d,\hII) -- (\d,\hII) -- (R);
\draw[thick] (A) -- (0,\hII);

\foreach \P in {A,L,R} \fill[] (\P) circle[radius=1mm];

% Tests
%\draw[red, thick] (0,0) -- (\d,0);
\end{scope}

\node[anchor=east] at (mytube.west) {$p_3=$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

